# Visual Studio Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'am using a new MacBook running on OS X 10.15.3  Catalina from scratch. I was/am installing from the gitup site, apache2,php and other requirements to finally install Magento 2.3.3. I am trying to download Visual Studio Code for MacOs. How can I drag the file to applications from downloads folder? I copy paste it to applications and after I wanted to open it and I got this error:
“Visual Studio Code” can’t be opened because Apple cannot check it for malicious software.
also it said This software needs to be updated. Contact the developer for more information.
Safari downloaded this file today at 15:29 from az764295.vo.msecnd.net.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I am a new Apple user. The answer was easy to find in system preferences, Security and Privacy. 
Open the application from this new developer anyway.